# Curl of a cross product idenitity

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am a bit confused, here is a wikipedia page mentioning various ways to write the curl of a cross product of 2 vectorfields: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities#Cross_product_rule

One of the identites is:

$$ \nabla \times (\mathbf{A} \times \mathbf{B}) = \nabla \cdot(\mathbf{B} \mathbf{A}^T)-\nabla \cdot(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}^T) = \nabla\cdot(\mathbf{B}\mathbf{A}^T-\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}^T)
$$

Is it a mistake to assume $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}^T$ is a matrix multiplication? Isn't a vector multiplied by the transpose of another vector just a dot product? But that wouldn't make sense since the left side is a vector, but both right sides would each be scalars, not to mention the right sides would each just be $0$. I have tried computing this out, but it's really difficult to make a meaningful connection. Even with small writing, the column vector spans the width of an A4 piece of paper. If anyone could quickly point out what this term is saying, I would be grateful. Thank you for reading

Comment: $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}^T$ is the rank-2 tensor that is basically the tensor product of $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$.  See the end of the previous subsection on divergence $\nabla\cdot(\mathbf{b}\mathbf{a}^T)$.